# jQuery $.ajax call to WCF service returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: wcf, jquery

(Update at end)

I'm working on an idea using unfamiliar technology.  I've written a few WCF services, but I've never done any advanced configuration.  This is my first dive into jQuery.  The premise is I create a WCF service to get branch information, to be retrieved by jQuery.

My first search yielded this page: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/WCF_JQUERY_ASMX.aspx#2 which I'm using as the base of my code.  I initially started off as a cross-site setup, which I got rid of to see if I could just get the thing working.  I've searched stack overflow and none of the posts resolve my 400 Bad Request issue.

Code from my web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="GeoDataBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="GDEPBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="GDBinding" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"/>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="GeoDataBehavior" name="GeoDataService">
    <endpoint address="" 
              binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IGeoDataService"
               behaviorConfiguration="GDEPBehavior"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

Code from my interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IGeoDataService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    List<BranchData> GetBranches();
}


// Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
[DataContract]
public class BranchData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string BranchNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string BranchName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string County { get; set; }
}
```

jQuery script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.6.1.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    /* help from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/WCF_JQUERY_ASMX.aspx
    */
    var varType;
    var varUrl;
    var varData;
    var varContentType;
    var varDataType;
    var varProcessData;

    function CallService() {
        // Thank you Bing: http://blueonionsoftware.com/blog.aspx?p=03aff202-4198-4606-b9d6-686fd13697ee
        jQuery.support.cors = true;


        $.ajax({
            type: varType,
            url: varUrl,
            data: null,
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: varContentType,
            dataType: varDataType,
            processdata: varProcessData,
            success: function (msg) {
                ServiceSucceeded(msg);
            },
            error: ServiceFailed
        });

        /*
        $.getJSON(varUrl, null, function (msg) {
            ServiceSucceeded(msg);
        });
        */
    }

    function GetBranchDataJson() {
        varType = "POST";
        varUrl = "GeoDataService.svc/GetBranches";
        varData = "";
        varContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        varDataType = "json";
        varProcessData = true;
        CallService();
    }

    function ServiceSucceeded(result) {
        var ddlResult = document.getElementById("ddlResult");
        for (var j = ddlResult.options.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) { ddlResult.remove(j); }

        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            var opt = document.createElement("option");
            opt.text = result[i].BranchName;
            ddlResult.options.add(opt);
        }
    }

    function ServiceFailed(jqXHR, errorType, errorThrown) {
        alert('error!\n' + jqXHR + '\n' + errorType + '\n' + errorThrown);
    }

</script>
<input name="WTF" type="button" onclick="GetBranchDataJson()" />
```

You'll note I'm using jQuery 1.6.1, not 1.3 from the tutorial.  The tutorial runs fine on my box and does everything as expected.  Unfortunately, my code does not.  I appreciate any help y'all can provide.

Oh, and here's a copy of the request from Fiddler:

```
POST http://localhost:16062/GeoDataService.svc/GetBranches HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Referer: http://localhost:16062/Default.aspx
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
Host: localhost:16062
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
```

**Update:** Ok, I passed "{}" as the Data query (apparently this is the right way to pass nothing to a method that does not take parameters), and I now get Unsupported Media Type.  And the trace exception is: System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: Content Type application/json; charset=utf-8 was sent to a service expecting text/xml; charset=utf-8.

Comment: So just for testing, I added a parameter to my GetBranches method, bool Test.  I updated my $.ajax call to pass in data: '{"Test": "true"}' and now I get an error in the trace: Content Type application/json; charset=utf-8 was sent to a service expecting text/xml; charset=utf-8.  I added ReceiveFormat=Json, but still get the error.  Is there something in the web.config I need to be changing?  Also, is there a correct way to pass null to a method that has no parameters (my original GetBranches)?

Comment: Can you check whether the service name in web.config matches the service name in the GeoDataService.svc file? They have to be exactly the same (i.e., class name with namespace)

Comment: Thanks for the idea, Carlos.  My namespace is GeoDataServices, and my service name is GeoDataService.  When I change the service name in web.config to GeoDataServices.IGeoDataService it throws the same error (when I changed it to GeoDataServices.GeoDataService, it told me to use the interface in the trace).  So, either configuration returns the same new ProtocolException.

Comment: You need to change the **service** name, not only the interface, something like <service behaviorConfiguration="GeoDataBehavior" name="**GeoDataServices.GeoDataService**"> and <endpoint ... contract="**GeoDataServices.IGeoDataService**" .../>

Comment: Wow, Carlos, you are the man.  If you want to post that as an answer, I'll mark it.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: For the record, it's sad that the WCF Test Client can query this service without issue and "just work", yet it's clear I had the configuration incorrect.

Comment: I updated by answer with the reason why you have this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The call by itself doesn't seem to have any problems - you should try to [enable tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) to see why WCF is considering the incoming request to be bad. I tried a similar code as the one you have (see below) and it worked just fine. Also, since the request is coming from the same domain (localhost:16062) as the service, you don't have any cross-domain problems.

**Update: solution based on the comment thread on the question**

The "name" attribute of the <service> element in the web.config **must match the fully-qualified name** (i.e., the namespace + the name) of the service class (i.e., the same value used in the .svc file). Otherwise you'll get a *default endpoint* added for your service which may or may not be what you want - by default you get a BasicHttpBinding endpoint, which is not what you wanted in your case.

This problem is un unfortunate side effect of a feature added in .NET Framework 4.0: [Simplified Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358768.aspx). Until .NET 3.5, every service needed to have an entry on web.config to configure it, and the config files for even the simplest applications (i.e., hello world) were big. So what happened is that, since 4.0, if WCF doesn't find a service element with a name which matches the fully-qualified name of the service, it will happily think that you want to use the default configuration. That's why it happens to "work" with the WcfTestClient at first.

```
public class StackOverflow_6526659
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IGeoDataService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        List<BranchData> GetBranches();
    }

    public class Service : IGeoDataService
    {
        public List<BranchData> GetBranches()
        {
            return new List<BranchData>();
        }
    }

    // Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
    [DataContract]
    public class BranchData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string BranchNumber { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string BranchName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Zip { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string State { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string County { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding { CrossDomainScriptAccessEnabled = true };
        WebHttpBehavior behavior = new WebHttpBehavior();
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IGeoDataService), binding, "").Behaviors.Add(behavior);
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(baseAddress + "/GetBranches");
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.GetRequestStream().Close();
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine("HTTP/{0} {1} {2}", resp.ProtocolVersion, (int)resp.StatusCode, resp.StatusDescription);
        foreach (var header in resp.Headers.AllKeys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", header, resp.Headers[header]);
        }
        if (resp.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
        }

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, Carlos.  With the trace log, here's the error: System.Xml.XmlException: The body of the message cannot be read because it is empty.  Now, I don't have a lot of experience with "raw" web service calls (typically I'm going .NET to .NET), so I don't know if this is too generic an exception to help.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Carlos.  Didn't know that about WCF 4.0 vs 3.5.  Again, really appreciate your help!