# ajax post request to wcf returning "400 bad request "

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, wcf

sorry for my English.

I have wcf method:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate ="TestFunction", Method = "POST",ResponseFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json,RequestFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle =WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    string TestFunction(string name);

public string TestFunction(string name)
    {

        return "Successed!";
    }
```

My ajax method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(function () {
           var wcfurl='http://192.168.200.100/Searching.BE.Service/WCFRESTService.svc/TestFunction';
           $.support.cors = true;
           jQuery.support.cors = true;
           $.ajax({
               crossDomain: true,
               type: 'POST',                                
               processdata: true,
               data:{"name":"Denis"},
               url: wcfurl,
               success: function (data) { alert(data); },
               error: function (data) { console.log(data);},
               ContentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
               dataType: 'json',
           });
       });
   </script>
```

Service returning:

```
{readyState: 4, responseText: "<?xml versi...", status: 400, statusText: "Bad Request"}
```

I tried using  JSON.string and etc. What is the problem?

Comment: Have you seen e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526659/jquery-ajax-call-to-wcf-service-returns-400-bad-request)?

Comment: @dee, how to add params fromWcfTestClient?

Comment: Was there any resolution to this?